# How to add subscribers with same Email ID registered on different websites?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, websites

Let me explain.

I have two websites created in magento admin **abc.domain.com** and **xyz.domain.com**. A customer registers from both websites using same email id.

Now I add that email ID to subscribers list programmatically. But only one row is inserted. I need two rows, each for both websites.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Today, I have struggled the issue but just little bit differ.
I just want to subscribe the newsletter on all website (single instance magento) with same email ID.
and finally I found the below extension and it works for me.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multistore-newsletter-subscription.html

Its model class can help you to understand the subscription for same email address.